# Mapbox GL cluster zoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to show all the markers when the user click on a cluster.

This is what I have done so far:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var cluster_features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: [
            'cluster-0',
            'cluster-1',
            'cluster-2'
        ]
    });
    var cluster_feature = cluster_features[0];
    if (cluster_feature && cluster_feature.properties.cluster) {
        map.jumpTo({
            around: e.lngLat,
            zoom: map.getZoom() + 2
        });
    }
});
```

This is adding 2 levels of zoom every time the user click on a marker. It works but sometimes I need to zoom even more to see the markers.

Any suggestion about how I could zoom to the actual markers with a single click?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a complicated solution given the current version of Mapbox-gl `0.37.0`.

> I'm trying to show all the markers when the user click on a cluster

There are two possible solutions given this one statement.

1. show markers plus clusters in the next zoom level or
2. show all markers (irrespective of the zoom level).

In `mapbox-gl`, the clustering functionality is provided by [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster).

As of `0.37.0`, there is no intuitive API to customise how supercluster works when you set source via `map.addSource...`

therefore you may need to use/import supercluster as a library dependency in your entry file where `mapbox-gl` is used (either via npm or otherwise).

**1. Using supercluster to find next zoom level for when markers uncluster.**

In supercluster, you can use the method `getClusterExpansionZoom(clusterId, clusterZoom)`, this gives you the next zoom for the selected cluster from where markers can be seen (whether that is `1,2,4,n` `zoomlevels` from `currentZoomLevel`.

```
var supercluster = require('supercluster');

let features;

map.on('load', function(e) {
  features = supercluster().load(FEATURES);
});

// helper function
function findNearestCluster(map, marker, i) {
  let clusterSelected = marker;
  // get bounds
  let south = map.getBounds()._sw;
  let north = map.getBounds()._ne;
  let bounds = [south.lng, south.lat, north.lng, north.lat];

  let currentClusters = i.getClusters(bounds, Math.floor(map.getZoom()));

  let compare = {
    lng: clusterSelected.geometry.coordinates[0],
    lat: clusterSelected.geometry.coordinates[1]
  };

  let minClusters = currentClusters.map(cluster => {
    let lng = cluster.geometry.coordinates[0];
    let lat = cluster.geometry.coordinates[1];

    return {
      id: cluster.properties.cluster_id,
      geometry: cluster.geometry,
      value: Math.pow(compare.lng - lng,2) * Math.pow(compare.lat-lat,2)
    };
  });

  return minClusters.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  });
}

map.on('click', function (e) {
  var cluster_features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: [
      'cluster-0',
      'cluster-1',
      'cluster-2'
    ]
  });

  var cluster_feature = cluster_features[0];

  // we need to find the nearest cluster as 
  // we don't know the clusterid associated within supercluster/map
  // we use findNearestCluster to find the 'nearest' 
  // according to the distance from the click
  // and the center point of the cluster at the respective map zoom

  var clusters = findNearestCluster(map, cluster_feature, features);
  var nearestCluster = clusters[0];

  var currentZoom = Math.floor(map.getZoom());
  var nextZoomLevel = supercluster()
      .getClusterExpansionZoom(nearestCluster.id, currentZoom);  

  if (cluster_feature && cluster_feature.properties.cluster) {
    map.jumpTo({
      around: e.lngLat,
      zoom: nextZoomLevel
    });
  }
});
```

**2. show all markers (irrespective of the zoom level).**

We do the a similar thing as above, but instead of using just `nextZoomLevel` / `getClusterExpansionZoom`, we can use the `getLeaves`.

> getLeaves returns all markers from the cluster -

```
var clusters = findNearestCluster(map, cluster_feature, features);
var nearestCluster = clusters[0];

var currentZoom = Math.floor(map.getZoom());

var getLeaves = supercluster()
    .getLeaves(nearestCluster.id, currentZoom, Infinity);
```

From here, you can render the leaves as `mapbox.Markers` if required, similar to `leaflet.markercluster`.

The problem with the second solution is that you need to remove/update the markers whenever the view has been changed, in order to reflect the current position of the mapview.

From a top-down perspective, this is ok, but if you start pivoting, the view render gets a bit jank, so I wouldn't recommend that from a UI perspective.

Answer (score 0):

What if you constructed a lineString from the coordinates of each point in the cluster_features and then did a [zoomTo-lingstring](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/)

Answer (score 0):

As @MeltedPenguin said (in [MapBox - Cluster Zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232134/mapbox-cluster-zooming/51324642#51324642))) .  You can do it without `SuperCluster`.  I search for several answers and finally did my own solution using coffeescript (you can convert it back to JS with tools like http://js2.coffee/):

```
    @clusterRadius = 30
    @map.on 'click', (e) =>
          features = @map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['markers_layer'] });
          if features && features.length > 0
            if features[0].properties.cluster
              cluster = features[0].properties

              allMarkers = @map.queryRenderedFeatures(layers:['markers_layer_dot']);
              self = @ #just a way to use 'this' un a function, its more verbose then =>    

              #Get all Points of a Specific Cluster
              pointsInCluster = allMarkers.filter((mk) ->
                pointPixels = self.map.project(mk.geometry.coordinates) #get the point pixel
                #Get the distance between the Click Point and the Point we are evaluating from the Matrix of All point
                pixelDistance = Math.sqrt((e.point.x - (pointPixels.x)) ** 2 + (e.point.y - (pointPixels.y)) ** 2)

                #If the distant is greater then the disance that define a cluster,  then the point si in the cluster
                # add it to the boundaries
                Math.abs(pixelDistance) <= self.clusterRadius
              )

              #build the bounding box with the selected points coordinates
              bounds = new (mapboxgl.LngLatBounds)
              pointsInCluster.forEach (feature) ->
                bounds.extend feature.geometry.coordinates
                return

              #Move the map to fit the Bounding Box (BBox)
              @map.fitBounds bounds, {padding:45, maxZoom: 16}

            else
              window.open('/en/ad/' + features[0].properties.propertyId)
```

On my page I have 2 layers based on the same source of data but with different attributes.  One that define all dots (without clusters) and another one which define dots and clusters.
For my display I use the "markers_layer" with clusters, and for calculate distance and stuff I use the other, as a DB of dots.

SOURCE:

```
  @map.addSource "markers_source_wo_cluster",
    type: "geojson"
    data:
      type: "FeatureCollection"
      features: []
    cluster: false
    clusterMaxZoom: 10
    clusterRadius: @clusterRadius

  @map.addSource "markers_source",
    type: "geojson"
    data:
      type: "FeatureCollection"
      features: []
    cluster: true
    clusterMaxZoom: 60
    clusterRadius: @clusterRadius
```

LAYER:

```
##============================================================##
## Add marker layer (Layer for QueryRender all dot without cluster)
##============================================================##
@map.addLayer
  id: 'markers_layer_dot'
  source: 'markers_source_wo_cluster'
  type: "circle"
  paint:
    "circle-radius": 0 #This are 1 pixel dot for ref only

##============================================================##
## Add marker layer
##============================================================##
@map.addLayer
  id: 'markers_layer'
  source: 'markers_source'
  type: 'symbol'
  layout:
    'icon-allow-overlap': true
    'icon-image':'pin_map'
    'icon-size':
      stops: [[0,0.4], [40,0.4]]
```